# apt update - could not connect

Tags: networking

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2, fresh install.
I have a /29 public network x.x.x.80/29

When I set my IP to x.x.x.83 everything works fine.
As soon I set my IP to x.x.x.82 I can not use apt update.

Here the error:

`apt update Err:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease  Could not connect to ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:1620::1620), connection timed out Could not connect to ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (109.202.202.202), connection timed out`

I also tried to change the archive to de.archive.ubuntu.com - same situation

But traceroute ch.archive.ubuntu.com works:

Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Did you change your routing tables? Look at `ip route`. Read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: Routing table is ok, google ist working. As soon as I change IP to .83 problem is gone. Is it possible that ubuntu blocks certain IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to get another public address range from my provider. Somehow the old ip address must have been blocked by someone.

With my new ip range everything runs perfektly.